# AWS S3 object failed to fetch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am trying to use the following 3d model. The object isn't fetching right. Please help

whenever i right:

```
fetch('https://s3.amazonaws.com/3dlearning.io/untitled.glb')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

I get error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mS8yN.png)

Comment: could you try `aws-sdk` for the get operation ? https://acloud24.com/blog/download-file-from-s3-using-node-js/

Comment: Works OK for me.

Comment: @jarmod Can ya share codesandbox

Comment: @PrabhatMishra haven't ever use that. I just wanted to put my file in AWS and host it through link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works fine for me:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://s3.amazonaws.com/3dlearning.io/untitled.glb')
  .then(res => console.log('good'))
  .catch(err => console.error('bad', err));
```

Comment: Hello, Can i email you?

Comment: Hi Suneel, there’s no DM facility on Stack Overflow afaik and everything is public. Happy to help here, if I can.

Comment: Sure no worries. I fixed the issue. Thank you! :)